# Cross DB query between Azure SQL Server VM on Azure Gov Cloud and Azure Public cloud

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-gov

I have an on-premises database which communicates with Azure SQL Sever VM on public cloud using linked server. Now we have a requirement to move the on-prem db to Azure Government Cloud.

After migration to Azure Gov cloud how can I maintain the connection for cross db query between SQL servers on Gov cloud and Public cloud? My understanding is Global vnet peering cannot be maintained between Gov cloud and on-prem cloud.

Is there a way to keep the functionality of cross DB query intact after migration?

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve this would be to move the Azure SQL Sever VM on public cloud to the Azure Gov cloud. When they are both in the same cloud it is possible to do cross server queries.

Since the data on the 2 servers are related, it may be that both belong in the Gov cloud.

Comment: The data in  Azure SQL Server VM on public is being accessed by other applications and DB in public cloud. Unfortunately, for now moving it to Gov is not possible. Is the any other approach I can take?

Comment: You could replicate data from the public cloud to a server in the gov cloud. But this would increase your costs.

Comment: Another approach would be to redesign your solution such that the cross server joins are not required. Get the data from the public cloud via an API.

Answer (score 0):

While you will not be able to use Global VNET peering between Public & Government clouds, you can use Azure Virtual Network Gateways to establish a VPN between the two clouds. If that is not an option for you, you can configure public IP endpoints for your SQL Servers on both ends. With this option will definitely want to establish firewalls or NSG rules to restrict any other outside traffic.